# Spring kafka - multiple consumers receiving same message

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using spring kafka to consume messages from kafka. Consumer listener is as below.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "topicName",
            groupId = "groupId",
            containerFactory = "kafkaListenerFactory")
    public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord record) {
       logger.info("Received Message from kafka topic " + record.topic() + " with record key " + kafkaRecordKey + " partition " + record.partition() + " offset " +record.offset());

   }
```

Single instance of application with ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory concurrency=6.

The topic has 6 partitions.

```
Time: 5/27/22 6:28:52.864 PM
message: Received Message from kafka topic payment-topic with record key ti9:a1956769-28d2-4329-a0ff-9003003a3cde partition 4 offset 325
thread: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-4-C-1
threadId: 69

Time: 5/27/22 6:28:52.864 PM
message: Received Message from kafka topic payment-topic with record key ti9:a1956769-28d2-4329-a0ff-9003003a3cde partition 4 offset 325
thread: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-3-C-1
threadId: 66
```

From above logs, it is clear that 2 consumers received same message from partition and offset and exactly same time.

Each thread continues processing the message. In the end one of the consumer fails with below error

```
Time: 5/27/22 6:28:52.887 PM
message: [Consumer clientId=consumer-payment-consumer-5, groupId=payment-consumer] Offset commit failed on partition payment-topic-4 at offset 326: The coordinator is not aware of this member.
thread: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-4-C-1
threadId: 69 

Time: 5/27/22 6:28:53.902 PM
message: Error handler threw an exception
thread: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-4-C-1
threadId: 69
   threadPriority: 5
   thrown: { [-]
     cause: { [+]
     }
     commonElementCount: 0
     extendedStackTrace: [ [+]
     ]
     localizedMessage: Seek to current after exception; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
     message: Seek to current after exception; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
     name: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException
```

I understand above error can when there is load or processing of the message takes time. In this case processing is less than a second and there are less than 10 messages in kafka topic.

Please advise on why multiple consumers receiving same message.

Also the error logs says "Offset commit failed on partition payment-topic-4 at offset 326" for message at offset 325

Library versions

```
Spring boot - 2.5.7
org.springframework.kafka.spring-kafka - 2.7.8
org.apache.kafka.kafka-clients - 2.8.1
```

Comment: share the code of your `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory`

Answer (score 1):

The process time of the record has to be less than `max.poll.interval.ms` otherwise the rebalance happens and it is likely the currently processed record offset is not committed therefore another assigned consumer fetches only from the previously committed offset for that partition.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#consumerconfigs_max.poll.interval.ms

Comment: Hi Artem, default value for max.poll.interval.ms is 5 mins. In logs above thread 66 and 69 received exactly same message at same time - 5/27/22 6:28:52.864 PM. The issue is clearly not due to processing time

Comment: I see . That cannot be. The APache Kafka claims not to have such a behavior with consumer group. Any chances you can share with us a simple project to reproduce? Perhaps you have another consumer which belongs to other group on the same topic…